# replace string from one file to other file

Tags: perl

```
open (HAN1, "<test1.txt") || die "not existing!";
open (HAN2, "test2.txt") || die "not existing!";

s/nameserver/nameserver/g;

    print  HAN2 $_;
    }
close(HAN1);
close(HAN2);
```

~

test1.txt

```
nameserver 10.66.80.10
nameserver 10.66.80.11
nameserver 10.66.80.11
```

test2.txt

```
search test.com
nameserver 99.66.80.10
nameserver 98.66.80.11
nameserver 98.66.80.11
```

After running the script test2.txt its removing other string content.

```
nameserver 10.66.80.10
nameserver 10.66.80.11
nameserver 10.66.80.11
```

But want the result test2.txt

```
search test.com
nameserver 10.66.80.10
nameserver 10.66.80.11
nameserver 10.66.80.11
```

Comment: [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8587937/edit)  and show the real Perl code you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;

    open (HAN1, "<test1.txt") || die "not existing!";
    open (HAN2, "<test2.txt") || die "not existing!";

    my $current;
    my @arr1 = <HAN1>;

    foreach $current (<HAN2>) {
        unless ($current =~ /nameserver/) {
            print $current;
            next;
        }
        foreach  (@arr1) {
            my($first,$second) = split (' ',$_);
            $current =~ s/^(nameserver\s+).+/$_/g;
            chomp($current);
            print $current;
            last;
        }
        shift @arr1;
    }
close(HAN1);
close(HAN2);
```

Comment: I tested your script and seems ok but outputs 'nameserver' twice. Perhaps it should be '$second' instead '$_' in substitute command and remove the next 'chomp' command or add a '\n' in next 'print'

Comment: Replace the 18th line by this "$current =~ s/^(nameserver\s+).+/$_/g;
".